# How can quality of a domestique be rated?

Tags: cycling

Various criteria, such as number of wins, UCI points, are good for comparing GC contenders and sprinters. Climbing times and wattage can say a lot about quality of a climber.

But quality of [domestiques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestique) is a very important factor in order to achieve team's objectives in any race, too. I am not able to think of some (at least partially) objective criteria to evaluate domestiques.

> - Are there some criteria by which performance of domestiques can be rated?
> - Are there some websites which give rankings/ratings of cycling domestiques?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A domestique's number one aim is to help their team leader win, so you can just count the number of wins a rider has been on the same team as. Cycle Sport magazine used to publish a list every year - I think it was usually one of Mark Cavendish's team mates at the top of the list.

Edit: Check the image posted with Martin's comment. It shows that in 2010 the "award" went to Bert Grabsch of HTC-Columbia. In fact 8 of the top 10 were HTC-Columbia riders - the team that Cavendish and Andre Greipel rode for that year.

Comment: I was able to get 2010 December issue of Cycle Sport magazine into my hands. And I can confirm that it contains a ranking called *Domestique of the Year*. See these pictures: http://i.stack.imgur.com/fdD6O.png and 
http://i.stack.imgur.com/amJz1.png (I hope that this can be considered fair use.)

Comment: The problem with just counting wins is that it favour domestiques on sprint teams, because they get a higher total of wins. A domestique for a grand tour winner could do a big job for his captain, but it won't show in the statistics as more than one win.